# Exposing fields for a search in Views

Tags: entities, nodes, search, views

I can add a filter for `node:title` and `node:body`, but then there's two separate search fields for the content. I also have some other exposed filters (checkboxes), but I need rather than two search fields to have just one normal search field. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same [issue on d.org](http://drupal.org/node/680442).
In short: it's better to enable `Search: search terms` filter (Drupal core search module needs to be enabled too).

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 6, the [Views Or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module might be of assistance. You can set up one exposed filter to search multiple fields that way (though it's a little tricky, and dare I say hackish?). Here's [a good tutorial from Krimson on this method](http://krimson.be/articles/views-searching-multiple-fields-one-exposed-filter).

The Search: search terms filter works great if you want to use core search (Core's 'search.module' must be enabled), and for most purposes, but if you want to do it for more advanced views, or without using core search (I rarely use it these days),

Another option is to use [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to create a field containing all the data you'd like to search, and just use that field as the exposed filter field in Views (while *displaying* the other independent fields).

Finally, a hackish way that can work sometimes involves setting all the 'filter identifiers' to the same value (requires a [views hack](http://drupal.org/node/451000#comment-4618570), at least while editing the view).

The best solution might be to write your own filter for Views... but that's pretty tough, especially with 3.x, as the API docs are in bad need of updating.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) module to work like a charm.

It allows to searche multiple fields on users, as well as nodes.  This is very convenient if you are trying to provide a user search field that goes through the whole profile.